# Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default - using xgboost classifier in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, xgboost, bayesian

As a part of ensemble learning function, I'm trying to train an xgboost classifier for binary classification. To make the process faster and more efficient I use `BayesianOptimization` for finding the best hyperparameters, and to do so I must define an objective function first.

My code is falling in the objective function part. It's not recognizing the function when it comes to the tunning part. Here is the code (only the xgboost part, the rest isn't relevant for the issue):

```
  k <- 10
  
  # Create k equally-sized folds
  folds <- caret::createFolds(train_target, k = k, list = TRUE, returnTrain = TRUE)
  
  bounds <- list("max_depth" = c(3L, 10L),
                 "eta" = c(0.001, 0.1),
                 "gamma" = c(0.0, 5),
                 "colsample_bytree" = c(0.1, 1),
                 "min_child_weight" = c(1L, 10L),
                 "subsample" = c(0.5, 1),
                 "nrounds" = c(200L, 500L))
  

  xgb_objective_function <- function(...) {
    # Create a list of all parameters passed
    params <- list(...)
    
    max_depth <- params$max_depth
    eta <- params$eta
    gamma <- params$gamma
    colsample_bytree <- params$colsample_bytree
    min_child_weight <- params$min_child_weight
    subsample <- params$subsample
    nrounds <- params$nrounds
    
    # Initialize an empty vector for fold errors
    fold_errors <- numeric(k)
    
    for (i in 1:k) {
      # Get the indices for the training and validation sets
      train_indices <- folds[[i]]
      valid_indices <- setdiff(seq_len(nrow(train_features)), train_indices)
      
      cv_train_features <- train_features[train_indices, ]
      cv_train_target <- train_target[train_indices]
      cv_valid_features <- train_features[valid_indices, ]
      cv_valid_target <- train_target[valid_indices]
      
      dtrain = xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(apply(cv_train_features, as.numeric)), label=as.numeric(cv_train_target))
      
      param <- list(max_depth = as.integer(max_depth),
                    eta = eta,
                    gamma = gamma,
                    colsample_bytree = colsample_bytree,
                    min_child_weight = min_child_weight,
                    subsample = subsample,
                    objective = "binary:logistic",
                    eval_metric = "auc")
      
      # Add the missing training command here
      cv_result <- xgboost::xgb.train(params = param, data = dtrain, nrounds = as.integer(nrounds), early_stopping_rounds = 100, silent = 1)
      
      cv_preds <- predict(cv_result, newdata = as.matrix(apply(cv_valid_features, as.numeric)))
      cv_preds <- ifelse(cv_preds > 0.5, 1, 0) # Convert probabilities to binary predictions
      fold_errors[i] <- mean(cv_valid_target != cv_preds)
    }
    
    return(list(Score = mean(fold_errors), Pred = NULL))
  }
  
  
  print('Next up: rBayesianOptimization for XGB')
  
  xgb_tuned_params <- BayesianOptimization(
    FUN = xgb_objective_function,
    bounds = bounds,
    init_points = 10, 
    n_iter = 15, 
    acq = "ucb", 
    kappa = 2.576, 
    verbose = TRUE
  )
```

This is the error: `Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default`.

I should note that `train_features` and `train_target` are defined earlier inside the ensemble learning.